# Fix XML undeclared prefix namespace error

Tags: php, xml, namespaces

The below XML and instructions is from an example posted by Google on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/. I'm attempting to use the exact example but apparently the XML is malformed because of the namespace. I tried to correct, but I'm too new to this. I'd appreciate if someone can advise how to correct.

```
To update the contents of an existing row, first retrieve the row to update, modify it as desired, and then send a PUT request, with the updated row in the message body, to the row's edit URL.

Be sure that the id value in the entry you PUT exactly matches the id of the existing entry. The edit URL is highlighted in the following row entry:



<entry gd:etag='"S0wCTlpIIip7ImA0X0QI"'>
      <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId</id>
      <updated>2006-11-17T18:23:45.173Z</updated>
      <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006"
        term="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"/>
      <title type="text">Bingley</title>
      <content type="text">Hours: 10, Items: 2, IPM: 0.0033</content>
      <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
        href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId"/>
      <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"
        href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full/rowId/version"/>
      <gsx:name>Bingley</gsx:name>
      <gsx:hours>20</gsx:hours>
      <gsx:items>4</gsx:items>
      <gsx:ipm>0.0033</gsx:ipm>
    </entry>
```

The error is:

```
'gd' is an undeclared prefix.
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a part of an larger XML document. More specific it looks like an Atom entry from an Atom feed with additional namespaces. I assume that string functions (regex maybe) where used to extract the entry from the document string. This broke the XML. Not only are the namespace prefix definitions for the additional namespaces are missing, the default namespace is missing, too. Usually all that definitions are done on the document element of the atom feed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't extract this at all, its simply what Google is showing on the link I pasted above. Somehow I'm supposed to use this to send updated data back to the API. You're probably right that its part of a larger structure, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: After some research, I just copied the headers from the 'Retrieving a list-based feed' section of the document and it worked. Thanks for the clues.